# row_sums vs findFreqTerms for subsetting TermDocMatrix to include words with a given min frequency

Tags: r, bigdata, sparse-matrix, tm, term-document-matrix

my question is straightforward. I have a (binary) TDM and I want to reduce the number of rows to include only those rows that appear in at least two documents:

I thought that these two methods would produce the same result in a binary matrix:

```
> rowTotals = row_sums(tdm)
> dtm2 <- tdm[which(rowTotals > 2),]
> dtm2
<<TermDocumentMatrix (terms: 208361, documents: 763717)>>
Non-/sparse entries: 34812736/159094025101
Sparsity           : 100%
Maximal term length: 154
Weighting          : binary (bin)

> #alternative probably faster:
> atleast2 <- findFreqTerms(tdm, lowfreq = 2)
> dtm2 <- tdm[atleast2,]
> dtm2
<<TermDocumentMatrix (terms: 340436, documents: 763717)>>
Non-/sparse entries: 35076886/259961683726
Sparsity           : 100%
Maximal term length: 308
Weighting          : binary (bin)
```

yet it is not so.. Could you help figuring out why it isn't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They produce the exact same result. You have a mistake in your second part. You are taking the frequency of 2 and more, while in the first part you are taking all the words with a frequency of 3 and more. If make sure both selection criteria are the same you will see that they will produce the same result. See code example below. Also speed comparison.

```
library(tm)

data("crude")
crude <- as.VCorpus(crude)
crude <- tm_map(crude, stripWhitespace)
crude <- tm_map(crude, content_transformer(tolower))
crude <- tm_map(crude, removePunctuation)
crude <- tm_map(crude, removeNumbers)
crude <- tm_map(crude, removeWords, stopwords("english"))

tdm <- TermDocumentMatrix(crude)

# via row_totals
row_totals <- slam::row_sums(tdm)
dtm_via_rowtotals <- tdm[which(row_totals > 2),]

<<TermDocumentMatrix (terms: 237, documents: 20)>>
Non-/sparse entries: 864/3876
Sparsity           : 82%
Maximal term length: 13
Weighting          : term frequency (tf)

# via findFreqTerms
freq_terms <- findFreqTerms(tdm, lowfreq = 3)
dtm_via_freq_terms <- tdm[freq_terms, ]

<<TermDocumentMatrix (terms: 237, documents: 20)>>
Non-/sparse entries: 864/3876
Sparsity           : 82%
Maximal term length: 13
Weighting          : term frequency (tf)
```

Are they the same?

```
all.equal(dtm_via_rowtotals, dtm_via_freq_terms)
[1] TRUE
```

Speed:

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(row_totals = {rowtotals <- slam::row_sums(tdm); dtm_via_rowtotals <- tdm[which(rowtotals > 2),]},
                               freq_terms = {freq_terms <- findFreqTerms(tdm, lowfreq = 3); dtm_via_freq_terms <- tdm[freq_terms, ]},
                               times = 1000L)

Unit: milliseconds
       expr    min     lq     mean median      uq     max neval
 row_totals 1.5039 1.6347 1.885161 1.7106 1.86085  9.3405  1000
 freq_terms 1.5696 1.6895 2.039345 1.7760 1.93525 99.0942  1000
```

The selection via row_totals is slightly faster. But that is because `findFreqTerms` actually uses `row_sums` to get the info and has some extra lines of code to check if you pass it an document term matrix and if the frequencies you request are actual numbers.

Comment: Silly me, I just forgot the equal sign. Thank you for the benchmark